# Extension works only after refreshing the extension and web page

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm developing the extension for linkedin , and i'm using the context menu also , when the context menu is cliked the iframe will open , but it only works when the service worker is active , but every time the service worker is going to inactive state , and in order run i need to refresh the extension and website every time

[image: showing service worker inactive][image][image]

background.js

```
var baseURL = "https://www.go1.page/";

var baseURLs = {
  "Add this page to contact":
    "https://flourishing-travesseiro-d38932.netlify.app/h/sc?link=",
  "Add this page to entity":
    "https://flourishing-travesseiro-d38932.netlify.app/h/se?link=",
  "Add Contact":
    "https://flourishing-travesseiro-d38932.netlify.app/h/se?link=",
 
};

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  for (let key of Object.keys(baseURLs)) {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      id: key,
      title: key,
      type: "normal",
      contexts: ["page"],
    });
  }

  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
    console.log("info", info);
    console.log("tab", tab);
    baseURL = baseURLs[info.menuItemId];
    var newURL = baseURL + info.pageUrl;
 

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      if (info.menuItemId === "Add this page to contact") {
        console.log("contact");
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
          tabs[0].id,
          { greeting: "contact" },
          function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        );
      } else if (info.menuItemId === "Add this page to entity") {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
          tabs[0].id,
          { greeting: "entity" },
          function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        );
      } else if (info.menuItemId === "Add Contact") {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
          tabs[0].id,
          { greeting: "addcontact" },
          function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

content.js

```
let profile = {};
let company = [];
let skillarray = [];
let education = [];
let projects = [];
let peoplelist = [];
const element = document.createElement("div");
element.setAttribute("id", "navButton");
element.innerHTML = `
    <style>
    #onepageextButton{
        z-index: 2147483640;
        position: fixed;
        transform: translateX(130%);
        top: 100px;
        bottom: auto;
        left: auto;
        right: 45px;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    #onepageext_badge_main{
        z-index: 2147483640;
        position: relative;
        transition: background-color 200ms linear;
        background-color:#fff;
        height: 32px;
        width: 32px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    .onepageext-slide_in{
        --slide-start: 130%;
        animation: slide-in 500ms forwards;
    }
    #onepageext-extension_badge_name{
        position: absolute;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .onepageextBtnContainer{
      display:flex;
    }
    .onepageextBtnContainer button .div,
    .onepageextBtnContainer div{
      width: 35px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    #onepageext-extension_outside{
    height: 90vh;
    width: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2147483647;
    top: 54px;
    left: auto;
    right: 16px;
    bottom: auto;
    }
    .onepageext-slide-out{
      --slide-end: 130%;
      animation: slide-out 500ms forwards;
  }
    #onepageext-extension_iframe{
      border-radius: 19px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: 0 54px 30px rgb(12 15 28 / 12%);
    }
    .onepageext-iframe-container{
      background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    height: 90vh;
    width: 320px;
    top: 50px;
    }

    #iframe-button {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      left: 15px;
    }
    .draggable {
      cursor: move;
      position: absolute;
      user-select: none;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="onepageextDragable" class="onepageextBtnContainer draggable">
    <div id="onepageext-extension_outside" class="onepageext-slide-out" style="display: none;"> 
    <button id="btn" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 6px; right: 25px; border: none; font-size: 18px;">X</button>
    <iframe id="onepageext-extension_iframe" lang="en" class="onepageext-iframe-container">
    </iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="onepageextButton" class="onepageext-slide_in" style="display: flex;">
    <div id="onepageext_badge_main">
    <div id="onepageext-extension_badge_name">    
    <img src="https://www.go1.page/static/media/logo.442e4794344196438517.png" width="32px" height="32px"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    `;

// If meet url and meet are not present
document.body.append(element);
let data = document.getElementById("onepageextButton");
let closebtn = document.getElementById("btn");
data.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let ele = document.getElementById("onepageext-extension_outside");
  let elem = document.getElementById("onepageextButton");
  if (ele.style.display == "none") {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    closebtn.style.display = "block";
    ele.className = "onepageext-slide_in";
    elem.className = "onepageext-slide-out";
  }
});

closebtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let ele = document.getElementById("onepageext-extension_outside");
  let elem = document.getElementById("onepageextButton");
  if (ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    closebtn.style.display = "none";
    elem.style.right = "42px";
    ele.className = "onepageext-slide_out";
    elem.className = "onepageext-slide-in";
  }
});

const iframe = document.getElementById("onepageext-extension_iframe");
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request, sender);
  let ele = document.getElementById("onepageext-extension_outside");
  let elem = document.getElementById("onepageextButton");
  if (ele.style.display == "none") {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    closebtn.style.display = "block";
    ele.className = "onepageext-slide_in";
    elem.className = "onepageext-slide-out";
  }
  if (request.greeting === "contact") {
    iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("contact.html");
  } else if (request.greeting === "entity") {
    iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("entity.html");
  } else {
    let finalsjson = {
      profile: profile,
      work: company,
      education: education,
      skills: skillarray,
      project: projects,
      people: peoplelist,
    };
    iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("contact.html");
    console.log("finaljson", JSON.stringify(finalsjson));
    console.log(peoplelist.length);
  }
});
// fetching linked in data
let profileId = "";
const _voyagerBase = "https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api";
if (window.location.href.includes("https://www.linkedin.com/in/"))
  profileId = window.location.href.split("/in/")[1].replace("/", "");

function getCookie(name) {
  const v = document.cookie.match(`(^|;) ?${name}=([^;]*)(;|$)`);
  return v ? v[2] : null;
}

function zeroLeftPad(n) {
  if (n < 10) {
    return `0${n}`;
  }

  return n.toString();
}

function getDefaultMonth(isStart) {
  return isStart ? 1 : 12;
}

function getDefaultDay(month, isStart) {
  return isStart ? 1 : maxDaysOfMonth[month];
}

function parseDate(dateObj, isStart) {
  const year = dateObj?.year;

  if (year === undefined) {
    return "";
  }

  const month = dateObj?.month ?? getDefaultMonth(isStart);
  const day = dateObj?.day ?? getDefaultDay(month, isStart);

  return `${year}-${zeroLeftPad(month)}-${zeroLeftPad(day)}`;
}

async function voyagerFetch(fetchEndpoint, optHeaders = {}) {
  let langHeaders = {
    "x-li-lang": "en-us",
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Get the csrf token - should be stored as a cookie
    const csrfTokenString = getCookie("JSESSIONID")?.replace(/"/g, "");
    // console.log(csrfTokenString);
    if (csrfTokenString) {
      const fetchOptions = {
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          ...langHeaders,
          accept: "application/vnd.linkedin.normalized+json+2.1",
          "csrf-token": csrfTokenString,
          "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
          "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        },
        referrer: window.location.href,
        body: null,
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
      };
      fetch(fetchEndpoint, fetchOptions).then((response) => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          const errStr = "Error fetching internal API endpoint";
          reject(new Error(errStr));
          console.warn(errStr, response);
        } else {
          response.text().then((text) => {
            try {
              const parsed = JSON.parse(text);
              resolve(parsed);
            } catch (e) {
              console.warn("Error parsing internal API response", response, e);
              reject(e);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      reject(new Error("Could not find valid LI cookie"));
    }
  });
}

async function profileView() {
  let endpoint =
    _voyagerBase + "/identity/profiles/" + profileId + "/profileView";
  const profileViewData = await voyagerFetch(endpoint);
  // console.log(profileViewData);
  profileViewData.included.map((item) => {
    if (item?.$type.includes("profile.Position") && item?.companyName) {
      let obj = {
        name: item?.companyName,
        position: item?.title,
        startdate: parseDate(item?.timePeriod?.startDate, true),
        enddate: parseDate(item?.timePeriod?.endDate, true),
        location: item?.locationName,
      };
      company.push(obj);
    } else if (item?.$type.includes("profile.Education") && item?.schoolName) {
      let obj = {
        institution: item?.schoolName,
        degree: item?.degreeName,
        field: item?.fieldOfStudy,
        startdate: parseDate(item?.timePeriod?.startDate, true),
        enddate: parseDate(item?.timePeriod?.endDate, true),
      };
      education.push(obj);
    } else if (item?.$type.includes("profile.Project") && item?.title) {
      let obj = {
        name: item?.title,
        startDate: parseDate(item?.timePeriod?.startDate, true),
        summary: item?.description,
        url: item?.url,
      };
      projects.push(obj);
    } else if (item?.$type.includes("profile.Certification")) {
      console.log(item);
    }
  });
}
async function contactInfo() {
  let endpoint =
    _voyagerBase + "/identity/profiles/" + profileId + "/profileContactInfo";
  const contactInfoData = await voyagerFetch(endpoint);
  // console.log(contactInfoData);
  profile.email = contactInfoData.data.emailAddress;
  profile.address = contactInfoData.data.address;
  profile.phone = contactInfoData.data.phoneNumbers;
  profile.dateofbirth = contactInfoData.data.birthDateOn;
}
async function skills() {
  let endpoint =
    _voyagerBase + "/identity/profiles/" + profileId + "/skillCategory";
  const skillsData = await voyagerFetch(endpoint);
  // console.log(skillsData);
  skillsData.included.map((item) => {
    if (item?.name) {
      let obj = {
        name: item?.name,
        level: "",
        keywords: [],
      };
      skillarray.push(obj);
    }
  });
}
async function advancedAboutMe() {
  let endpoint = _voyagerBase + "/identity/profiles/" + profileId;
  const advancedAboutMeData = await voyagerFetch(endpoint);
  // console.log(advancedAboutMeData);
  profile.firstname = advancedAboutMeData.data.firstName;
  profile.lastName = advancedAboutMeData.data.lastName;
  profile.summary = advancedAboutMeData.data.summary;
  profile.label = advancedAboutMeData.data.headline;
  profile.linkedinprofile = {
    username: profileId,
    url: window.location.href,
  };
  profile.profilepicture =
    advancedAboutMeData.included[0].picture.rootUrl +
    advancedAboutMeData.included[0].picture.artifacts[3]
      .fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment;
}

async function people() {
  let endpoint =
    _voyagerBase +
    "/identity/profiles/" +
    profileId +
    "/following?count=100&q=followedEntities";
  // let endpoint =
  //   "https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/relationships/peopleYouMayKnow";
  const peopleData = await voyagerFetch(endpoint);
  console.log(peopleData);
  peopleData.included.map((item) => {
    if (item?.$type.includes("shared.MiniProfile") && item?.firstName) {
      let obj = {
        firstName: item?.firstName,
        lastName: item?.lastName,
        occupation: item?.occupation,
        profilepicture:
          item.picture.rootUrl +
          item.picture.artifacts[3].fileIdentifyingUrlPathSegment,
      };
      peoplelist.push(obj);
    }
  });
}
if (window.location.href.includes("https://www.linkedin.com/in/")) {
  profileView();
  contactInfo();
  skills();
  advancedAboutMe();
  people();
}
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("onepageextButton"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  console.log("eleme", elmnt);
  /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2 + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1 + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
console.log(window.location.href);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "1Page",
  "description": "1Page",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "host_permissions": ["https://*.linkedin.com/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "16.png"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["index.html", "contact.html", "entity.html"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]
}
```